# Explanation of systemd-logind in Auth.log

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Im seeing the following line in my Auth.log file

`systemd-logind[761]: Power key pressed.`

Can this be triggered any other way(script, error, panic)? I ask because unless my cat has become smart enough to press the power button then I think it's being triggered elsewhere.

Does this only show if the physical power button is pressed, or could it be being triggered elsewhere?

Update-

```
sudo udevadm trigger -v -n -g power-switch
/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input2/event2
/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0C:00/input/input0/event0
/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0E:00/input/input1/event1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The message is shown under exactly one condition: one of the devices under /dev/input has sent a KEY_POWER or KEY_POWER2 event, and yes, systemd-logind receives those directly from the kernel without any external "triggers".

Though, this could also include the "Power" buttons [on regular keyboards](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3JeuL.jpg) as well as some kinds of remote controls. Use `udevadm` to find out which devices are being monitored for this kind of event:

```
$ udevadm trigger -v -n -g power-switch
/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input7/event3
/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/device:00/LNXVIDEO:00/input/input8/event4
/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0D:00/input/input5/event1
/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0E:00/input/input6/event2

$ udevadm trigger -v -n -g power-switch | xargs -i cat {}/../name
Power Button
Video Bus
Lid Switch
Sleep Button
```

Also: Do not underestimate cats.

Comment: So I was right, something physical has to be pressed or closed. Il run those commands later to see wat exactly it is. Thank you

Comment: Well, someone *could* maybe trick logind by setting up a virtual input device via uinput, but... what's the point? That requires root.

Comment: Ya that sounds unlikely lol. But with the command you gave me it shows 2 power buttons and a suspend (presumably the case power switch and motherboard switches)